# Half integer values in Sympy

Tags: python, sympy, physics

In the package `sympy.physics.quantum.spin` there is a function `m_values` which is called by a lot of the other functions in the package. It takes as input an integer or half-integer, and returns a tuple. Here is the source code, obtained from Github:

```
def m_values(j):
    j = sympify(j)
    size = 2*j + 1
    if not size.is_Integer or not size > 0:
        raise ValueError(
            'Only integer or half-integer values allowed for j, got: : %r' % j
        )
    return size, [j - i for i in range(int(2*j + 1))]
```

This functions works as I expect it to for integer values. However, if I put in a half-integer value, this function returns an error. Here is an example:

```
from sympy.physics.quantum.spin import m_values
m_values(0.5) #can also try m_values(3/2)
```

This code produces the error

```
ValueError: Only integer or half-integer values allowed for j, got: : 0.500000000000000
```

So clearly the issue is that `size.is_Integer` is returning `False`. How should I input `j` into `m_values` so that the function works for half-integers?

Comment: `Rational(1,2)` might work.

Comment: Ah I wasn't aware of `sympy.Rational` type, but it worked. Thank you.

Comment: `S.Half` is a singleton constant (like `pi == S.Pi` that you can use, too.